# Is there any way I can avoid iterating over a query set with single value?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I get a queryset object every time i want some data from models.
So when i say,

```
"items = Items.object.get(value=value)"
```

I get --

```
"<QuerySet [<Item-name>]>"
```

I have to iterate through the queryset object to get the data and I do that with

```
"items[0]"
```

Is there any way I can avoid this?

Edit: I meant `"items = Items.object.filter(value=value)"`

Comment: Shouldn't this be `Items.objects.get(..)`?

Comment: you can use `first()`, if you're always sure its just one result.

Answer (score 2):

first of all `items = Items.objects.get(value=value)` does not return a queryset, 
rather it returns an object of `<Items: Items object (1)>`

To get the first(or just one result) or last date from the object, do this `Items.objects.first()` or `Items.objects.last()`

To get the desired data without using its index position, then you can filter it like this `Items.objects.filter(value=value)`

Comment: Your post is wrong buddy. Check this. You can see it on your console too. https://imgur.com/a/IoDhP2S

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken. `items = Items.object.get(value=value)` will not give you a queryset, but an object. `items = Items.object.filter(value=value)`
would give you a queryset.

Filter method will always give you a queryset, because; in order to minimize the need of database hits, django considers you might add additional filters through your code. So if you not execute that queryset, e.g. by using `list(your_queryset)`  django never hits the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
# when you are using 'get' in your query, you don't need to iterate, directly get an access to the field values

try:
    items = Items.object.get(value=value)
except Items.DoesNotExist:
    items = None

if items:
    print(items.value)
```